After migrating from Xamarin to Net8.0, Back Button does not work anymore
I am using Visual Studio 17.10.5.
I had a application in Xamarin C# (Android) which I have migrated to Net8.0.
All the application is working well except one thing :
In the class public class MVision : AppCompatActivity, I create a back button with the code : DonneActivite().SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true).
After migration to Net 8.0 : this button do nothing and the function
public override void OnBackPressed() {  is not called.
If I go back with the phone button, it goes back correctly.
I have done tests with simulator and with a phone.
Have you any idea to make the button working ?
Best regards
